# How to achieve O(n) worst-case time complexity for this function?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having issues with a certain task. It's not a homework or anything, it's rather a personal matter now. And I want to know if there's even a solution for this...

The point is to achieve **expected O(n) worst-case time complexity** of a function, that takes 2 string arrays as input (let's call first one `A`, and the second array `B`) and should return an array of integers where each element represents an index of the corresponding element in array `A`.

So, this is how a function should look like:

```
private static int[] GetExistingStrings(string[] A, string[] B) { ... }
```

- Array `A` contains all possible names
- Array `B` contains names which should be excluded (i.e. if some of the names stored in `B` array are also in the `A` array, their indices should not be included in an output int[] array; it's also possible that this array can contain some random strings which are not necessarily may present in the `A` array OR it may even be empty.

For example, if we have these arrays:

```
string[] A = { "one", "two", "three", "four" }; // 0, 1, 2, 3
string[] B = { "two", "three" }; // Indices of "two" and "three" not taken into account
```

The function should return:

```
int[] result = { 0, 3 }; // Indices of "one" and "four"
```

At first, I tried doing it the obvious and simple way (with nested for-loops):

```
private static int[] GetExistingStrings(string[] A, string[] B)
{
    LinkedList<int> aIndices = new LinkedList<int>();

    for (int n = 0; n < A.Length; n++)
    {
        bool isExcluded = false;
        for (int m = 0; m < B.Length; m++)
        {
            if (A[n].Equals(B[m]))
            {
                isExcluded = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isExcluded)
        {
            aIndices.AddLast(i);
        }
    }

    int[] resultArray = new int[aIndices.Count];
    aIndices.CopyTo(resultArray, 0);
    return resultArray;
}
```

I used LinkedList because we can't possibly know what the ouput's array size should be and also because adding new nodes to this list is a constant **O(1)** operation. The problem here, of course, is that this function (as I assume) is **O(n*M)** time complexity. So, we need to find another way...

My second approach was:

```
private static int[] GetExistingStrings(string[] A, string[] B)
{
    int n = A.Length;
    int m = B.Length;

    if (m == 0)
    {
        return GetDefaultOutputArray(n);
    }

    HashSet<string> bSet = new HashSet<string>(B);
    LinkedList<int> aIndices = new LinkedList<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!bSet.Contains(A[i]))
        {
            aIndices.AddLast(i);
        }
    }

    if (aIndices.Count > 0)
    {
        int[] result = new int[aIndices.Count];
        aIndices.CopyTo(result, 0);
        return result;
    }

    return GetDefaultOutputArray(n);
}

// Just an utility function that returns a default array
// with length "arrayLength", where first element is 0, next one is 1 and so on...
private static int[] GetDefaultOutputArray(int arrayLength)
{
    int[] array = new int[arrayLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Here the idea was to add all elements of `B` array to a HashSet and then use it's method `Contains()` to check for equality in a for-loop. But I can't quite calculate time complexity of this function... I know for sure that the code in the for-loop will execute `n` times. But what bugs me the most is the HashSet initialization - should it be taken into account here? How does it affects time complexity? is this function **O(n)**? Or **O(n+m)** because of HashSet initialization?

Is there any way to solve this task and achieve **O(n)**?

Comment: Rather then a linked list, use a list with pre-set capacity. The Constructor of Lists allow you to specify a capacity. Something like A.Count should be a good upper bound. Do not use a linked list until you *actually* ran into problems. Their performance is hilariously bad compared to a good old list. At worst adding something at the end, requires going through the entire existing list (to find the element you need to add something at).

Comment: "Is there any way to solve this task and achieve O(n)?". No. The best you can get is probably O(m*log(n)).

Comment: Under what circumstances is knowing the complexity important?  Are you running code like this millions/billions of times and are having performance problems or are you trying to pre-optimize something?

Comment: HashSet is amortized O(1) for lookups, so doesn't factor into the overall complexity.  AddLast() is O(1).  You have a single for-loop so it is O(n).  Populating the hashset and copying to the array are O(n) as well, so it stays O(n).  The code is not optimal, but not what you asked about.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm trying to understand this time complexity thing (Big-O Notation) especially for functions with 2 variables as input. I remember I saw a task similar to mine and one of it's conditions were to achieve `O(n)` worst-case time complexity for a function with 2 string arrays (as input) and in a function you needed to simply check each element of both arrays for equality. I didn't believed that `O(n)` is possible here, so I had to ask out of curiosity.

Comment: @HansPassant wow, is this really a `O(n)` approach?! - I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused not only because I'm a newbie in this "department", but also because there's so much different opinions on that matter. For example, the first answer below.
Can you also please explain (in short) what do I need to do to make this code more optimal?

Comment: The hashset uses O(n) storage, trading memory for speed is one of the standard tricks.  Use List instead of LinkedList to improve locality of reference, change the return type to `IEnumerable<int>` so you don't have to copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `n` elements in `A`, `m` elements in `B`, and the strings are of length `k`, the expected time of a hashmap approach is `O(k*(m + n))`.  Unfortunately the worst time is `O(km(m + n))` if the hashing algorithm doesn't work. (The odds of which are very low.)  I had this wrong before, thanks to @PaulHankin for the correction.

To get `O(k*(m + n))` *worst* time we have to take a very different approach.  What you do is build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) out of B.  And now you go through each element of `A` and look it up in the trie.  Unlike a hash, a trie has guaranteed worst case performance (and better yet, allows prefix lookups even though we aren't using that).  This approach gives us not just expected average time `O(k*(m + n))` but also the same worst time.

You cannot do better than this because just processing the lists requires processing `O(k*(m + n))` data.

Comment: I think you've got a typo -- I calculate the worst case for hashing is `O(km(n+m))` assuming you build a hashtable of B and look up all the elements of A in it (and your hashtable uses a linked list of items with the same hashcode).

Comment: @btilly Can you please clarify how did you calculate `O(k*(m + n))` for my second approach? You see, I'm a newbie in this... so, in my understanding: 1. Initialization of HashSet and copying an array to it is an `O(n)` operation (space complexity, I believe???);  2. Single for-loop that executes `n` times, inside which we're checking whether the element in `A` is stored in the created `bSet` -> it's still `O(n)` because HashSet `Contains()` method is in fact a constant `O(1)` operation;  3. Copying to a newly created array is also a linear time operation - `O(n)`. Am I right?

Comment: @Faize13 When people talk about hash algorithms they often implicitly assume that computing a hash value is `O(1)`.  But in fact it isn't.  The longer the string you are hashing, the longer it takes to compute a hash value.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you could rewrite your second approach using LINQ, while also selecting case-insensitive string comparison:

```
public static int[] GetExistingStrings(string[] first, string[] second)
{
    var secondSet = new HashSet<string>(second, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    return first
        .Select((e, i) => (Element : e, Index : i))
        .Where(p => !secondSet.Contains(p.Element))
        .Select(p => p.Index)
        .ToArray();
}
```

The time and space complexity is the same (O(n)). It's just a more fancy way to do the same thing.